# .isStrikethrough(index) return wrong answer

Tags: google-apps-script

i have a code that return some char from file, if the char is Strikethrough, the char will be normal but if it's not Strikethrough the char will be bold.
the text is from file with 3 lines with char Strikethrough and not Strikethrough.
the problem is that the line listOfparagraph[paragraphIndex].editAsText().isStrikethrough(index) work only with the first paragraph' from the second it's return wrong answer (true all the time).
what to do?
this is the code:

```
function ot()
{
var listOfparagraph = DocumentApp.openById(theIdOfTheFile).getBody().getParagraphs();
// the number of char to find
var c = 40;
var paragraphIndex=0;
var paragraph = listOfparagraph[paragraphIndex].getText().toString();
var massege= '';
var index =0;
while(c>0)
{
  if(listOfparagraph[paragraphIndex].editAsText().isStrikethrough(index)== false && paragraph[index]!=' ')
  {
    massege+="<b>"+paragraph[index]+"</b>";
    c--;
  }
  else
  {
    massege+=paragraph[index];
  }
  
  if(paragraph.length-1==index)
  {
    paragraphIndex++;
    index=0;
    paragraph=listOfparagraph[paragraphIndex].getText().toString();
  }
  else
  {
    index++;
  }
}
}
```

if the text is: (there is'nt Strikethrough here so it's italic)
abc *def g*hij
b*vfr* hytg juyh
zxs edc *nhy*u

the return text will be:
**abc** def g**hij**
**b**vfr **hytg juyh**
**zxs edc** nhy**u**

i tried to change the text and change the index manually, always same wrong answer.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input situation and the sample output values you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: i edit it to explain thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an ananswer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of changing the text.

I create a simple test document as shown below with 3 paragraphs.  I would prefer to get the start and end of the strike through text and then use that for start and end.  But that would require more thought than I can currently afford.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function changeText() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();

    // shift the first paragraph off the list to show comparison
    paragraphs.shift();

    paragraphs.forEach( paragraph => {
        let text = paragraph.editAsText();
        let length = text.getText().length;
        let i = 0;
        while( i < length ) {
          if( text.isStrikethrough(i) ) {
            text.setStrikethrough(i,i,false);
          }
          else {
            text.setBold(i,i,true);
          }
          i++;
        }
      }
    );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Text.setStrikethrough()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setStrikethrough(Integer,Integer,Boolean))
- [Text.setBold()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setBold(Integer,Integer,Boolean))

Comment: Thanks, this is a very nice code. my problem is that The code should return the text (or rather send it by email) and not change it  in the sorce (after the sending is finished it's change it in the sorce to strikethrough). and i need that the number of char to send\change can change according to needs and not change the entire text. that why i used with var paragraph = listOfparagraph[paragraphIndex].getText().toString(); and not only with listOfparagraph[paragraphIndex].editAsText().

Comment: That’s not what you asked for.

Comment: I can not tell from your OP or your code what you want.

Comment: This is what I meant in what I wrote "i have a code that return some char from file, if the char is Strikethrough, the char will be normal but if it's not Strikethrough the char will be bold" you right it's not clear...

Comment: there is a way read one char from paragraph? and why the code that i wrote not working? For some reason it's allways listOfparagraph[paragraphIndex].editAsText().isStrikethrough(index) return true and not matter if is trikethrough or not

Comment: I modified the code as follows theWized an it work' not clear why but it's work so...

 let paragraphToSearch = listOfparagraph[paragraphIndex].editAsText(); and !paragraphToSearch.isStrikethrough(index)/*== false */